# How many nearest neighbours in a classifier by default?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithm

I've been running a classifier on my data with the 'NearestNeighbors' method. I've learned that I can specify the number of neighbours used with the following command:

```
 Classify[data, Method -> {"NearestNeighbors", "NeighborsNumber" -> X}]
```

However, I can't seem to find anywhere how many neighbours the classifier uses when I **don't** specify the number with the `NeighborsNumber` option. As a result, I'm not exactly sure what the "default" classifier is doing.

Does anyone have any insight into this?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably picks an appropriate value by some (internal) heuristics. Use `Information` to get the parameters that were used for a particular case.

```
c = Classify[{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {1, 1, 2, 2}, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"];

Information[c, "MethodOption"]

(* Method -> {"NearestNeighbors", "NeighborsNumber" -> 1, 
  "DistributionSmoothing" -> 0.5, "NearestMethod" -> "KDtree"} *)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was aware that one could ask for lots of information from the classifying function, but didn't know about the method option in particular. Thanks!